# How do I find the point on a paraboloid closest to the given point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the point on the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ closest to the point $(1, 1, 1)$. How do I do that? I'm told I need to use the gradient of the function. I've calculated it to be equal to $(2x, 2y, -1)$. I've found a similar problem [here](http://%5Cfrac%7Bd%5Cphi%7D%7Bdx%7D) but I'm having trouble understanding the answer.

Comment: The gradient vector you've computed is normal to the paraboloid. Using this, you can compute the normal line from the point $(x, y, x^2 + y^2)$. The point $(1, 1, 1)$ should lie on the normal line of its closest point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point on the parabola with equation $z=x^2+y^2$ has coordinates $(x,y,x^2+y^2)$. Can you write down the distance from this point to $(1,1,1)$? You want to minimize this distance.

**Hint**

Minimizing the *square* of the distance might be easier, but that occurs for the same point on the parabola (why?).

Note that due to symmetry, this will happen when $x=y$ which allows you to reduce this to a single variable problem.

Comment: The distance would be $D=\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (x^2 + y^2 - 1)}$ right? So to minimize that I'd need to calculate $\frac{dD}{dx}$ and $\frac{dD}{dy}$ and set them to 0, right?

Comment: That's a possibility, but the square root makes it slightly more annoying - see the hint above.

Comment: I see. So then I get the equation $4x^3 - x - 1 = 0$. The smallest of the roots of this equation is the solution for x and y then, right?

Comment: That equation has only 1 real root but yes, that corresponds to the minimal distance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The distance is given by $$d=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2}$$ and for $z$ write $$z=x^2+y^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the way you started, the nearest point $(x,y,z)$ on the paraboloid to $P=(1,1,1)$ will be one for which the normal line passes through $P$. Flipping this around, this means that the line through $P$ and $(x,y,z)$ must be parallel to the normal at that point. This line has direction vector $(x,y,z)-P$ and the parallelism condition can be expressed via a cross product: $$(2x,2y,-1)\times((x,y,z)-(1,1,1)) = (2yz-y-1,1+x-2xz,2y-2x) = 0.$$ You also have $z=x^2+y^2$; solve this system of equations. You can discard one of the equations generated by the cross product as only two of them are independent.